trapmf's second argument must be a parameter vector
I am trying to evaluate my FIS with eval(input, fis) and in doing so I got the folowing error when previously I useed  fis = readfis ('dc_motor.fis') to get my FIS
evalfis ([45 -23], fis)
error: trapmf's second argument must be a parameter vector
>>


My FIS include the following inputs and output:
[Input1]
Name= 'Error'
Range= [-97.5 +97.5 ]
NumMFs = 5
MF1='Nl':'trapmf', [-67-66 -65 -32.5 ]
MF2='Ns':'trimf' , [-65 -32.5 0 ]
MF3='Z' :'trimf' , [-32.5 0 32.5]
MF4='Ps':'trimf',  [0  32.5  65]
MF5='Pl':'trapmf', [32.5 65 66 67]

[Input2]
Name ='Edot'
Range=[-54 54]
NumMFs=5
MF1='Nl':'trapmf',[-38-37 -36 -18]
MF2='Ns':'trimf', [-36 18  0]
MF3='Z' :'trimf', [-18  0  18]
MF4='Ps':'trimf', [0  18  36]
MF5='Pl':'trapmf, [18 36  37 38]


[Output1]
Name ='U'
Range=[-255 255]
NumMFs=5
MF1='Nl':'trimf', [-155 -103.3  -51.66]
MF2='Ns':'trimf', [-103.3 -51.66  0]
MF3='Z ':'trimf', [-51.66  0   51.6 ]
MF4='Ps':'trimf', [0  51.66  103.3]
MF5='Pl':'trimf', [-255 -170 -85 0 85 170 255]






Above is what I tried.
I expect to understand  what that message error is telling me about the second argument because the second arguments is the fis word as documentation is showing.

Please STOP SHOUTING. It won't get you help any faster. It's also really rude to SHOUT at people you're asking for free help to solve your problem. Please turn off your CAPS LOCK.

When you write “[-67-66 -65 -32.5 ]”, did you mean to put a space between -67 and -66? Because that would mean something totally different!

The second argument to function trapmf
has to be a four value vector [a b c d] with a < b <= c < d. If you don't provide the four numbers there's no
trapezoid defined. These second arguments are those you have explicitly set in the fis file.
So the error trapmf's second argument must be a parameter vector is the result of your not providing a  vector [a b c d] in [-67-66 -65 -32.5 ]. Just typing [-67-66 -65 -32.5 ] in octave will get evaluated to [-133 -65 -32.5 ] since there's no space between -67 and -66, as @Cris Luengo observed. There's no error in the array expression itself, but you provided three values instead of four.
The same with [-38-37 -36 -18] in the second input.
Then the error becomes trimf's second argument must be a parameter vector. The second argument to the function
trimf has to be a three value vector,
[a b c] with a < b < c in order to have the triangle defined. Thus, 'trimf', [-255 -170 -85 0 85 170 255] doesn't work
out. Replacing it with the version from your previous question, 'trimf', [51.6 103.3 155] the error persists.
It is caused in this case by 'trimf', [-36 18 0] - here the problem is that you don't have a < b < c; probably you missed
the minus sign in front of 18: 'trimf', [-36 -18 0].
With this fourth correction the evaluation goes through and you get the result.
